# What is the difference between this two derivatives

Tags: derivatives

Why I must use the quotient rule to find the derivative of $\dfrac{2}{x^2}$ and in the case of $\dfrac{x^3}{2} + \dfrac{3x}{2}$  I should use the product rule?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:
$$
\dfrac{2}{x^2}=2x^{-2}
$$
and you can use the product rule.

More general:

The quotient rule for $\dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ ghives the same result as the product rule for $f(x)[g(x)]^{-1}$ ( can you prove this result?)

Comment: The quotient rule can be derived from the product rule if you have the patients for negative exponents. I also use this method so i don't have to memorize the stupid thing.

Comment: The right answer to the first one is -4/x^3

Comment: Yes, with the product rule with negative exponent it's easy. In general this is the more efficent when the numerator is a constant.

Answer (score 0):

No you dont need the quotient rule since 2/x^2=2x^(-2). Can you take it from here?
The other question is not answered by the Product rule. Take D(f+g) = Df + Dg